# Change url when sending file with Express

Tags: javascript, express

I want to send an HTML file as a response but when it does it keeps the current url. I have read about the `location` method but it does not work for me, I would like something like:

The source url is this: `localhost/login`

Sending this answer

```
res.location('/live').sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../pages/live.html"));
```

I was trying to get something like this

- Url in browser `localhost/live`
- With my rendered HTML file

I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request via AJAX, and send html content as string, then write it to document.

Front-End code:

```
fetch('/your-route')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
        document.write(data)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `.location` you are only setting the response header field of location to be equal to `/live`. You would have to add a status code of 302 to actually change the url. But when adding a status code of 302 you would cause  a redirect and the send file will not be shown as the browser will try to GET `/live`. So you have to have a listener for `GET /live` that returns your html file.
Or you could directly use res.redirect to redirect to the in that case needed `/live` handler.